# Today extension not changing size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, today-extension

I am trying to change the height of my todays widget, however it does not work.

I am doing this inside my `TodayViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 100);
}
```

Any reason why this does not work?

Comment: look into storyboard design oncce and for setting autolayout and other refer this link https://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/

Answer (score -1):

Try this it may helpful to you.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.preferredContentSize.frame;

newFrame.size.width = 200;
newFrame.size.height = 200;

[self.preferredContentSize setFrame:newFrame];
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to set width to 0, which doesn't make sense, because in this case widget won't be visible, the framework just ignores your changes.

You can update height leaving default width value:

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.preferredContentSize.width, 100)];
```

Comment: Thanks, but setting the width to zero is aright, because the framewrok ignores the width anyways.

Comment: The width value is ignored in Today extension